# How do I parse this type of expressions?

Tags: python, parsing, expression, operator-precedence

I don't have a compilers background so I am not sure if this is a commmon thing in that area. Are there any standard techniques to parse expressions like this? (Say, tab indicates the depth)

```
And
    A + B = 1
    C + D = 1
    Or
       P + Q = 1
       K = 1
    And
       Q = 1
       R = 2
```

Should be parsed as:

```
((A+B=1) AND (C+D=1) AND ((P+Q=1) OR (K=1)) AND ((Q=1) AND (R=2)))
```

I am not sure if I should resort to a stack based evaluation? I am currently trying out one and I'll post a working code if I can get it running.

Any suggestions on a simple way to achieve this?

Comment: What's the context? Does it have to be "safe"? Or could you change your syntax slightly and use Python with `eval()` or similar? For example, `((A+B==1) and (C+D==1))` is Python syntax.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot change the input. I am parsing some XML files and managed to parse the expressions themselves into a string. How I format the string is upto me but the order of evaluation and all still needs care. Also, I don't want to evaluate anything but want to say, get a string for printing.

Comment: are you parsing the expression into trees? Then evaluating them by subbing in numbers for those variables?

Comment: +1 for an interesting question, but I'm slightly confused -- are you only asking about parsing, or about how to do evaluation as well?

Comment: @MattFenwick: Sorry what I meant was I am not too concerned about evaluating the expressions for now. I am only trying to obtain a string representation of the input.

Comment: Isn't `((A+B=1) AND (C+D=1)...` a "string representation of the input" already?

Comment: @BenHoyt: Note that I am talking about the first multi-line string that does not have any parenthetical text and not the second one (which is the one I want from the first) which contains proper order of evaluation.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you are asking about how to parse expressions built out of operators with varying precedences and associativities -- absolutely.

One effective approach is called "top down operator precedence", and maybe also "operator precedence", and "precedence climbing" parsing.  Here are some nice sources explaining the approach in detail:

- [Pratt parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pratt_parser) (also the [original paper](http://mauke.hopto.org/stuff/papers/p41-pratt.pdf))
- Douglas Crockford's [take](http://javascript.crockford.com/tdop/tdop.html) on it
- a Pythonist's [take](http://effbot.org/zone/tdop-index.htm) on it
- a [Java version](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/)

The really neat thing is how little code it actually takes.

Key concepts are:

- prefix vs infix vs mixfix
- precedence:  is `3 + 4 * 5` parsed as `(3 + 4) * 5` or `3 + (4 * 5)`?
- associativity:  is `x - y - z` parsed as `x - (y - z)` or `(x - y) - z`?

Coincidentally, I have just been learning this stuff recently and ended up writing a an article on my blog about a similar approach to operator parsing, which you can find [here](http://mfenwick100.blogspot.com/2013/07/operator-parsing.html).  In my approach, I deal with infix, prefix, postfix, and mixfix operators (i.e. `? :`); precedences and associativities are all specified in tables; I use a stack to keep track of operators whose operands haven't yet been found.  The parser then builds a parse tree, where each node is a subexpression.